# Jboss shared libraries in web applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jboss, shared-libraries

We have got 3 webapplications running in the jboss 4.2.3.I have found that all these 3 webapps have 95% of common libraries.
I am planning to move common ones to Jboss/server/[profile]/lib so that I don have to bundle up all the necessary ones in the webapps.
I feel it would be good and would also reduce the perm gen space that is being currently used.

I just wanted to ask the community here whether what I am doing is the standard approach or is there anything wrong in doing that?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins jboss version is 4.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems reasonable to me as long as all web applications use the same version of these common libraries and you accept the fact that if you need to upgrade a library for any reason then all web applications are affected.
You should also make sure that the libraries moved to the shared location do not have dependencies in libraries that are part of your web application (avoid classloading issues)

Answer (score 4):

We use to do that as well by placing common libraries in the lib dir. Turned out to be a nightmare for sysadmiins to update individual apps. We eventually decided to make the war contaiin all required jars to minimize extra steps for the SAs. Made it easier for the QA department as well. It will work just depends on how your QA and SA groups feel about it.